RuntimeError Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda 0 and cuda 1
I am trying to reun the below script. But getting a Runtime error. Please I need your help on this issue.
# Set device to cuda:1 at the beginning
device = torch.device("cuda:1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

#pretrained model path and 4 bit quantized model of LLava
MODEL='llava-v1.5-13b'

model_name = get_model_name_from_path(MODEL)

print(f"Model Name: {model_name}")
print(os.listdir(MODEL))

#import the images from a picture directory

#path to thte pictures directory
path = 'Pictures/*.jpg'

#List to store images and their correponding file names
images = []
filenames = []

#read each images
for filename in glob2.glob(path):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    images.append(img)
    filenames.append(filename)

print(colored('Now, about to load the Pre-trained model.', 'yellow', attrs=['reverse', 'blink']))

# Import the tokenizer and the pretrained model for Llava
try:
    tokenizer,model,image_processor,context_len=load_pretrained_model(
        model_path=MODEL,model_base=None,model_name=model_name#,load_4bit=True
    )
    print(colored('Model loaded successfully...', 'green', attrs=['reverse', 'blink']))
except Exception as e:
    print(colored(f"Error loading pretrained model: {e}", 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink']))
    raise

# Move model to device
model.to(device)

# Ensure vision tower is on the correct device
vision_tower = model.get_model().get_vision_tower()
if isinstance(vision_tower, list):
    for tower in vision_tower:
        tower.to(device)
else:
    vision_tower.to(device)

# Show the user the image name and content of the chosen image.
# The required image index must be within the range.

require_image = 3
if require_image < len(filenames):
    print(f"Image Name: {filenames[require_image].split('/')[-1]}")  # Displaying the image name
    image = images[require_image]

    # To show the image
    img = mpimg.imread(filenames[require_image])
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
else:
    print(f"Image index {require_image} is out of range. Total images: {len(filenames)}")


#Function to convert the required image into a tensor and process it for LLava model
def process_image(image):
    args={"image_aspect_ratio":"pad"}
    image_tensor=process_images(image,image_processor,args)
    return image_tensor.to(device,dtype=torch.float16)
    # return image_tensor.to(device,dtype=torch.float32)

#processing the chosen image above using the function developed in the previous step
processed_image=process_image(image)
print(type(processed_image), processed_image.shape)


#Defining the model that will be used for conversation with the images
CONV_MODE="llava_v0" #Change the version

#using thte prompt template as per the LLava torch documentation
def create_prompt(prompt:str):
    conv=conv_templates[CONV_MODE].copy()
    roles=conv.roles
    prompt=DEFAULT_IMAGE_TOKEN+"\n"+prompt
    conv.append_message(roles[0],prompt)
    conv.append_message(roles[1],None)
    return conv.get_prompt(),conv

#the following is the default system message used by the AI model
prompt,_=create_prompt("Describe the image")
print(colored(prompt, 'cyan', attrs=['reverse', 'blink']))

#Creating a function to interrogate the images using the model downloded
def ask_image(image:Image, prompt:str):
    image_tensor=process_image(image).to(device)
    prompt,conv=create_prompt(prompt)
  
    # Get input ids and convert to tensor
    input_ids_list = tokenizer_image_token(prompt, tokenizer, IMAGE_TOKEN_INDEX)
    input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids_list).unsqueeze(0).to(model.device)

    stop_str=conv.sep if conv.sep_style!=SeparatorStyle.TWO else conv.sep2
    stopping_criteria=KeywordsStoppingCriteria(keywords=[stop_str],tokenizer=tokenizer,input_ids=input_ids)

    with torch.inference_mode():
        output_ids=model.generate(
            input_ids,
            images=image_tensor,
            do_sample=True,
            temperature=0.02, #change the value according to your needs
            max_new_tokens=512,
            use_cache=True,
            stopping_criteria=[stopping_criteria]
        )

    return tokenizer.decode(
        output_ids[0,input_ids.shape[1]:],skip_special_tokens=True
    ).strip()

#using the above paramers for the prompting as well as the processing of the image, tokenize of the prompt, encoding
result=ask_image(image, "Describe the image for the general audience.")
print(textwrap.fill(result,width=110))


and I am getting the below error. Can anyone help me solve this error.?

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:1! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper_CUDA__cudnn_convolution)

I am trying to use .to(device) so that it can be in a same machine however it is not working. Please check; especially the ask_image(image:Image, prompt:str) function.
I really need to run the script. I don't know what is going on since I am trying to move the tensor in a same device but not working.

Stabbing in the dark, but I think this can occur when you mix floating points, eg 8 vs 16 vs 32?

I am using torch.float16 to avoid such an issue. But, do you have any idea what should I need to change?
